# Multiprocessing for a RabbitMQ Queue Pika

Tags: python, rabbitmq

I am working with `RabbitMQ` queues. I want to run multiple consumer object instance through a single program. Below is my `Operator` class that creates `1 producer and 1 consumer`

```
class Operator(object):

    def __init__(self, delegate: callable, identifier):
        """
        Create a new instance of the Operator and initialize the connections
        """
        self._queue_details = self._get_queue_details()
        self._host_ip = self._queue_details['IP']
        self._port = self._queue_details['Port']
        self._username = self._queue_details['Username']
        self._password = self._queue_details['Password']
        self._input_queue_name = self._queue_details['ReadQueueName']
        self._output_queue_name = self._queue_details['WriteQueueName']
        self._error_queue_name = self._queue_details['ErrorQueueName']
        self._delegate = delegate
        self._identifier = identifier
        self._queue_connection = None
        self._input_channel = None
        self._output_channel = None
        self._error_channel = None
        self.is_busy = False
        self.mark_to_terminate = False

    def __del__(self):
        # close connections
        self._queue_connection.close()

    @staticmethod
    def _initialize_channel(connection, queue_name, durable):
        channel = connection.channel()
        channel.queue_declare(queue=queue_name, durable=durable)
        return channel

    @staticmethod
    def _get_queue_details() -> dict:
        return ConfigurationManager().get_value('queueDetails')

    @staticmethod
    def _get_connection(username, password, host_ip, port):
        connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(
            credentials=pika.PlainCredentials(username, password), host=host_ip, port=port))
        return connection

    def initialize_operator(self):
        connection = self._get_connection(self._username, self._password, self._host_ip, self._port)
        self._queue_connection = connection
        self._input_channel = self._initialize_channel(connection, self._input_queue_name, durable=False)
        self._output_channel = self._initialize_channel(connection, self._output_queue_name, durable= True)
        self._error_channel = self._initialize_channel(connection, self._error_queue_name, durable=True)

    def consume(self):
        self._input_channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
        self._input_channel.basic_consume(self._process_incoming_message, queue=self._input_queue_name)
        self._input_channel.start_consuming()

    def _push_to_queue(self, channel, response):
        channel.basic_publish(exchange='', routing_key=self._output_queue_name, body=response,
                                properties=pika.BasicProperties(delivery_mode=2))  # make message persistent

    def _process_incoming_message(self, channel, method, properties, message):
        self.is_busy = True
        processed_result, is_error = self._delegate(message)

        if is_error:
            self._error_channel.basic_publish(exchange='', routing_key=self._output_queue_name, body=processed_result,
                                                properties=pika.BasicProperties(delivery_mode=2))
        else:
            self._output_channel.basic_publish(exchange='', routing_key=self._output_queue_name, body=processed_result,
                                                properties=pika.BasicProperties(delivery_mode=2))

        # send in the final ack of the process.
        channel.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)

        # close connection if to avoid receiving messages
        if self.mark_to_terminate:
            self._queue_connection.close()

        self.is_busy = False
```

And from my main script I spin up the agents like below:

```
# spins up the agent
for count in range(spin_up_count):
    instance = Operator(self._translate_and_parse, f'Operator: {time.time()}')
    instance.initialize_operator()
    process = Process(target=instance.consume)
    process.start()
    self._online_agents.append((instance, process))
```

The problem is when I go for a `process.start()` it throws me a `TypeError`

> TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects

**Complete Stack trace**

```
File "C:/Users/adity/Documents/PythonProjects/Caligo/Caligo/QueueService.py", line 201, in _scale_up
process.start()
File "C:\Users\adity\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 105, in start
self._popen = self._Popen(self)
File "C:\Users\adity\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 223, in _Popen
return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
File "C:\Users\adity\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 322, in _Popen
return Popen(process_obj)
File "C:\Users\adity\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 65, in __init__
reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
File "C:\Users\adity\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't instantiate your `Operator` objects prior to starting the forked processes. You also can't make `instance.consume` the target of the forked process.

The `target` method of the `Process` instance is what should create the `Operator` instance and then call the `consume` method.

If you need to manage the forked processes you should keep track of the process IDs and use signals to communicate with them.

Comment: would it be possible for you to share some piece of code related to what you mean by `The target method of the Process instance is what should create the Operator instance and then call the consume method` ? I am not able to find a valid code for this

Comment: Help other people help you by providing a repository (preferably on GitHub or GitLab) that contains the complete, running set of code you're working on. By providing that other people (like myself) could open pull requests and more easily provide assistance.

Comment: Thank you for that. I've posted up a repo for the same. I didn't have the time to actually create a `Readme` But the code is heavily commented. If you need anything feel free to report. Or mention here. [link to the repo](https://github.com/ImCarrot/RabbitMQLoadBalancer)

Comment: Thanks for providing the code. I will review it this week as time allows.

Comment: were you able to figure it out?

Comment: Hello! I have been busy with other work. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: Not a problem. I've been stuck on it for a week now. I could really use some help.

Comment: Hey thanks for the merge request. I am a little away now so I'll be testing it out tomorrow but I was going through your changes. Can you please elaborate a bit on the `stop_event`. Is it supposed to be used in case I want to shut down a consumer ? Would you be able to showcase the usage for it? I really appreciate you pulling out time for this.